# Get share point 2013 unique list column items and bind to a table using OOB

Tags: 2013, list

Hi i am new to sharepoint and javascript, i have a very urgent requirement to get list columns from a sharepoint list my requirement is below.

i have a sharepoint 2013 list as below

[image]

where "step" is a single line text and service line is a choice menu

i have to create a table in the below format

[image]

i.e get the unique column(service line & step) values(BPM, BPS... & A, B, C,... ) from the list and calculate their corresponding amounts, i.e the amounts of all items in the list which have common criteria as A & BPM, B& BPM, ......, A& BPS, ...... ETC, should get added and sum of the amounts have to be displayed. i have to implement this by without server side code

please help..

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your SharePoint list in Microsoft Excel. To do this, navigate to your list in  your browser > from the ribbon click the List tab > under the Connect & Export group click Export to Excel.
2. In Excel, highlight all the data including the headers > click the Insert tab in the ribbon > click PivotTable > click OK in the Create PivotTable window that pops up
3. From the PivotTable Field List pane on the right, drag your Service Line field into the Row Labels area, then drag your Step field into the Column Labels area, then drag your Amount field into the Values area.
4. At this point you might not quite have what you need, i.e. the amounts might not be adding, but rather counting. In this case look at the Values area in the PivotTable Field List pane; it might says "Count of Amount". If this is the case click the little down arrow next to "count of Amount" > click Value Field Settings > select Sum > click OK.

You should now have a table in the format that you need.

If you need this table in SharePoint, you can just copy-paste the pivot table into another tab in Excel, ensuring when you paste that you paste "values" only. Then you can create a new list on SharePoint by importing from a spreadsheet.